# Date difference in a column

Tags: python, r, dataframe, date

everyone.

I have been trying to create a function that can help me find a difference between 2 date in either python or R. The issue is that the date are in a single column of a data frame.

Basically, I am trying to subtract a date in one row of the data frame from the the other row in the data frame for multiple row.

I have attached a screen shot for reference.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please do no use screenshots of data, provide a reproducible example.

You likely want:

```
df['interval'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['STATEMENT_FROM_DD'], dayfirst=False)
                    .diff().dt.days
                  )
```